# How to make variable global across entire class

Tags: php, class

Very simple question, is it possible to make a variable that is retrieved from outside of a class, 'global' to the whole class so that I do not have to call the 'global $variable' at the beginning of each method?

**This is what I am currently doing:**

```
class test{
    public function testing(){
        global $globalVariable,

        // Do something
    }
    public function testing_two(){
        global $globalVariable,

        // Do something
    }
}
```

**In other words, can I import variables into the construct function and therefore make them accessible to the entire class without having to call 'global' for each method?**

**UPDATE**

Not sure if I have made it too clear with what I would like to achieve. Please see below:

```
$globalVariable = 'hello';

class test{
    public function testing(){
        global $globalVariable,

        // Do something
    }
    public function testing_two(){
        global $globalVariable,

        // Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: You are looking for a `static` property.  `public static $myvar`, accessed in the class as `self::$myvar` or outside the class` as `test::$myvar`

Comment: Just pass it as parameter to the constructor function and assign it to a private property.

Comment: See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

Comment: @FelixKling this will break if he needs a really global variable, in the sense of it being changed outside the class. Global database connection resources come to mind.

Comment: @Eugen: Global variables are a bad design decision anyways IMHO. Code gets more difficult to maintain and refactor if it grows.

Comment: @EugenRieck, that is exactly what I am trying to do!! Database and connection variables passed to an entire class. They are not going to change outside of the class so this is not a problem, however, they need to be accessible to the entire class and its methods. Currently I achieve this by writing 'global $DATABASES' at the top of each method.

Comment: @FelixKling, to a certain degree, I completely agree that global variables are a poor design decision. However, in the case of databases and connections where they are likely to change or be added, it is necessary to include global variables so the class itself does not have to be edited when a database is altered or added.

Comment: @Ben: Why are they global? Are you changing the database connection during the runtime of the script? Why not pass it as parameter to the constructor (dependency injection). There are many design patterns to avoid global variables (for a good reason).

Comment: @FelixKling I agree with you 100% that global variables are bad design - really. The problem is (and will be for 10+ more years), that there is a lot of code out there, that we have no power to chagne for one or the other reason. Moving a global var into the class (albeit by a crutch for the moment) should be considered a first laudable step into getting rid of it at a later point, when it is possible.

Comment: @BenCarey: You are awfully wrong. Continue to do so and you will learn the hard way.

Comment: No, the databases and connections do not change during the runtime of the script. They are defined on a separate page (outside of the class) and are therefore only accessible if I call 'global' when using them in any of the methods. I think the solution (as you say), lies in the construct function as I can call it as global there and then reference it throughout the class. However, references are deprecated so how can I do this?

Comment: What am I wrong about? My class has to connect to a database and I do not want to define the databases within the class as this would be poor design! Correct? Therefore the databases must be called into the class using global. How else can I do it?

Comment: @BenCarey a DB connection IS changed outside the class all the time! This is true for most resource type vars.

Comment: What changes about the connection? You certainly use it to retrieve values and put values into the database but during the execution of the script the database connection should be consistent, shouldn't it?

Comment: @EugenRieck, how is it changed?

Comment: @BenCarey: Correct. Instead of defining inside, define it outside and pass it via the constructor. Just don't use a global variable for that. That's all.

Comment: This might be helpful as well: [The best way to share database connection between classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596251/the-best-way-to-share-database-connection-between-classes)

Comment: Thank you @hakre. How do I pass it to the constructor? Obviously the constructor will look like __contruct($var), but how will it get $var when the class is initiated?

Comment: All sorted, thanks guys. I wasn't clear about what I wanted to achieve but @dan has supplied the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To clear up how to do it:

You most likely want to do something like this
`include('database.php');`. At that very point everything you included there is global to your script. Now if you have a class like the above you add a constructor:

```
class testclass
{
    private $db;

    public function __construct($db)
    {
       $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function yourmethod()
    {
       $this->db->prepare(); // And so on
    }
}
```

Let's assume your global variable is called $db in the global scope. You can just construct your object now using `new testclass($db);`. When you now use `$this->db` in all your methods there is no need to use the global statement.

Comment: THANK YOU!! This is exactly what I was looking for, all I wanted was confirmation. Out of interest, what is the benefit (point), of a reference?

Comment: The approach above has several benefits. Firstly it makes your code clearer. Everyone inspecting the class from your documentation now sees that this class depends on a database object passed to it. Additionally you can define an interface for your connection and pass different types of connections into the class as long as they implement the interface. This also helps if you want to test your code at a later point. That way you can simply exchange objects. Overall it's much better to oversee everything because you don't rely on the global state being the way you need it in your class.

Answer (score 2):

Pass that variable as a property of the class

```
class test
{
    private $globalVariable = '';

    public function testing()
    {
        $this->globalVariable = 'set-som-value';
    }

    public function testing_two()
    {
        $this->globalVariable = 'Do Extra Work';
    }
}
```

and you can change the variable visibility with the words **private**, **public** and **protected**, where private makes the variable accessible only into that class, protected makes the variable available in classes that extends that particular class, and public makes the variable accessible from everywhere.

**Global outside the class**

```
global $globalVar;
$globalVar = 'SomeVal';

class test
{
    public function testing()
    {
        global $globalVar;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice but I didn't explain in enough detail what I am trying to achieve. The '$globalVariable' is defined outside of the class so the above answer is not relevant. My fault, apologies.

Comment: Again, that is not what I am looking for. I do not want to call 'global' for each method. I want the variable to be accessible to the whole class. See @dan's answer

Answer (score 2):

Just use a reference:

```
class test{
    private $myvar;

    //use __ or old syntax to your liking
    function test() {
        global $globalVariable;
        $myvar =& $globalVariable;
    }

    public function testing(){
        //Use $this->myvar

        // Do something
    }
    public function testing_two(){
        //USe $this->myvar

        // Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: References are deprecated aren't they?

Comment: @BenCarey: Definitely not. However what you try to achieve looks specifically wrong and you should revise what you want to do, because there must be something better.

Comment: @Ben: No, they are not. Passing references at call time is deprecated: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Comment: IMHO the verdict is still waaaay out, if this feature will disappear: I personally think of it as an important part of the language, and that removing it would be a crippelning move. Others might agree or disagree. (Talking of references, not passing references!)

Comment: Ah, I was under the impression that they were, apologies. I am pretty sure that this answer is exactly what I am looking for. However, could I not just forget the reference and call 'global $globalVariable' in the construct, and then just use $globalVariable around the methods?

Answer (score 0):

This might help. I have a var outside my class I use for mysqli.

```
             <?php
             $DB_NAME = 'database';
             $DB_HOST = 'host';
             $DB_USER = 'user';
             $DB_PASS = 'password';

             $linkID = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);

             if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                  printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
                  exit();
             }


             $Test = new Test($linkID);


                 class Test {

                     public $linkID;

                     function __construct($linkID){ $this->linkID = $linkID; }

                     public function new_mysql($sql) {
                         $result = $this->linkID->query($sql) or die($this->linkID->error.__LINE__);
                         return $result;
                     }

                     public function do_query() {
                         $sql = "SELECT `name` FROM `contacts`";
                         $result = $this->new_mysql($sql);
                         while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                             print "Test $row[name]<br>";
                         }
                      }
                 }

         ?>
```

Now the database details are passed to the class as a helper. Hope this helps.