# TCPDF import variables to extension

Tags: php, codeigniter, class, tcpdf, extends

I'm using TCPDF and Codeigniter. I'm trying to create a custom header with information from my MYSQL-DB: `$header_content`.

Allthough I can't import the variable into the class MYPDF without getting an error tha the variable doesn't exits.

How do I import the variable into the class?

I'm sure there is an easy solution, I just can't figure it out! :)

**controller/pdf.php**

```
class Pdf extends CI_controller { 

    public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('item_model');
    }


   public function create($nr = 1)
   {
        $data['pd']= $this->item_model->get('personal_details');

        require_once APPPATH.'third_party/tcpdf/tcpdf.php';    

        $this->load->view('create_1', $data);
    }
}
```

**View/create_1.php**

```
    $header_content = $pd->fname.' '.$pd->sname;
    $header_font = $pd->font.;

    class MYPDF extends TCPDF
    {
        function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
        }

        //Page header
        public function Header() 
        {
            // Set font
            $this->SetFont($header_font, '', 10);

            // Title
            $this->Cell(0, 15,  $header_content, 0, false, 'L', 0, '', 0, false, 'M', 'M');
        }
    }

    // create new PDF document
    $pdf = new MYPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
```

Comment: Variables (like `$header`) of the parent function are not in scope, it's not run unless you call it with `parent::`, and even then you can't access them. You _can_ access public and protected variables of the object itself, so `$this->whateveryouneed`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
global $header_content ;
$header_content = '123123213dd213';

class MYPDF extends TCPDF
{
    function __construct(  )
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    //Page header
    public function Header() {

        global $header_content ;


        // Set font
       $this->SetFont('helvetica', '', 10);

        $this->Cell(0, 15,  $header_content , 0, false, 'L', 0, '', 0, false, 'M', 'M');
    }


}
```

Much thanks to Merianos Nikos's answer at [How to make variable global across entire class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9240694/how-to-make-variable-global-across-entire-class)

This works just fine. But is it the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
class MYPDF extends TCPDF
{
    public $header_content;

    //Page header
    public function Header() 
    {
        // Set font
        $this->SetFont($header_font, '', 10);

        // Title
        $this->Cell(0, 15,  $this->header_content, 0, false, 'L', 0, '', 0, false, 'M', 'M');
    }
}


// create new PDF document
$pdf = new MYPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->header_content= $pd->fname.' '.$pd->sname;
```

It works for me. Maybe you can try use Attributes.

Comment: Please comment your code a bit / write some info text to make it a proper stand alone answer.